# find out the public ip address range provided by my ISP's DHCP server

Tags: dhcp

I am working at home with an ISP provided network (like everyone else) and I need to connect to a server at work. For security reasons, the production server (the one at the working place) need to check the IP addresses, so I have to send my IP address to our System Administrator.

The annoying thing is my public IP address changed too rapidly, and I do not want to bother our System Administrator too much. Also, it is NOT possible to have VPN, so connecting from home is the only possibility.
Is there a way to figure out the IP address ranges that will be dynamically assigned to me, so I can send that range to our System Administrator?  I am using Ubuntu.
Thanks!